# XSLT - sorting by date

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

I'm looking at converting this XSL template from sorting a-z to date ascending and descending. There are two tags that I could utilise to sort date by:

```
<delivery_start_date>05-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
```

and

```
<machine_date>20150205</machine_date>
```

I had tried applying sort like this:

```
<xsl:sort select="@machine_date" data-type="numeric" order="ascending"/>
```

However that resulted in no styling being applied to the XML. The template I have is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>

          <course>
            <title>Managing Your Research Project</title>
            <course_code>167</course_code>
            <provider_name>Institute For Academic Development</provider_name>
            <referral_url/>
            <course_category>MScR Comp,PhD Comp,PhD SCE Res Plan,PhD MVM Res Plan,PhD HSS Res Plan,MScR SCE Res Plan,MScR MVM Res Plan,MScR HSS Res Plan</course_category>
            <provider_category>Course</provider_category>
            <description><![CDATA[
            <p>Project management is a core skill for most jobs and being a researcher is no different.&nbsp;&nbsp; This workshop is designed to help you take control of your research and support you in the successful completion of your PhD and future research projects.</p>
<p>This course, which is aimed at all postgraduate researchers, explores how you can apply project management principles to research projects.&nbsp;&nbsp; By attending the course you will learn how to:</p>
<ul>
<li>Clearly define your project to ensure it is successful.</li>
<li>Identify stakeholders and plan how to engage and communicate with them effectively to ensure your research has impact.</li>
<li>Define clear roles and responsibilities for the individuals involved in executing the research.</li>
<li>Develop a high-level plan for the whole research project including project time-lines, budgets and plans to manage project risks.</li>
<li>Identify time critical activities so you can prioritise these.</li>
<li>Develop detailed plan for shorter term activities to effectively manage your time.</li>
<li>Monitor the progress of your project and what action to take when the project is not progressing as planned.</li>
</ul>
<p>The workshop is interactive and you will have opportunities to learn project management tools through group activities as well as having time to reflect on your own research.</p>
<p>This course relates to domains A1, A3, B2, C2, and D3 of the <a href="http://www.ed.ac.uk/schools-departments/institute-academic-development/research-roles/research-only-staff/career-management/researcher-framework">RDF</a>.</p>
            ]]></description>
            <further_details/>
            <contact_details>
                <email>iad.phd@ed.ac.uk</email>
                <phone>0131 651 7188</phone>
            </contact_details>
            <single_attendance>-1</single_attendance>
            <prerequisites/>


                <delivery>
                      <delivery_start_date>15-Apr-2015</delivery_start_date>
                      <machine_date>20150415</machine_date>
                      <event_group_id>10532</event_group_id>
                      <max_places>25</max_places>
                      <bookings>0</bookings>
                      <status>CURRENT</status>
                      <waiting_list>Y</waiting_list>
                      <reminder_url/>
                      <delivery_title/>
                      <delivery_description/>
                      <delivery_url/>
                      <delivery_keywords/>
                      <allow_booking>P</allow_booking>
                      <schedule>
                            <event>
                              <machine_date>20150415</machine_date>
                              <start_date>15-Apr-2015</start_date>
                              <start_time>09:30</start_time>
                              <end_time>16:30</end_time>
                              <final_booking_date>14-Apr-2015</final_booking_date> 
                              <day_of_week>Wednesday</day_of_week>
                              <tutor/>
                              <location>
                                <room>Room 1.07, Main Library</room>
                                <building>Central Area</building>
                              </location>
                            </event>
                      </schedule>
                      <eligibility/>
                      <eligibility_display>DO NOT DISPLAY THIS</eligibility_display>
                      <eligibility_rules>
                        <eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years </eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule>
                      </eligibility_rules>
                      <costing>
                            <charging_type>Charging URL</charging_type>
                            <charge_url/>
                      </costing>
                </delivery>

                <delivery>
                      <delivery_start_date>09-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
                      <machine_date>20150209</machine_date>
                      <event_group_id>10531</event_group_id>
                      <max_places>25</max_places>
                      <bookings>0</bookings>
                      <status>CURRENT</status>
                      <waiting_list>Y</waiting_list>
                      <reminder_url/>
                      <delivery_title/>
                      <delivery_description/>
                      <delivery_url/>
                      <delivery_keywords/>
                      <allow_booking>P</allow_booking>
                      <schedule>
                            <event>
                              <machine_date>20150209</machine_date>
                              <start_date>09-Feb-2015</start_date>
                              <start_time>09:30</start_time>
                              <end_time>16:30</end_time>
                              <final_booking_date>08-Feb-2015</final_booking_date> 
                              <day_of_week>Monday   </day_of_week>
                              <tutor/>
                              <location>
                                <room>Room 1.07, Main Library</room>
                                <building>Central Area</building>
                              </location>
                            </event>
                      </schedule>
                      <eligibility/>
                      <eligibility_display>DO NOT DISPLAY THIS</eligibility_display>
                      <eligibility_rules>
                        <eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years </eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule>
                      </eligibility_rules>
                      <costing>
                            <charging_type>Charging URL</charging_type>
                            <charge_url/>
                      </costing>
                </delivery>

          </course>


          <course>
            <title>How to be an Effective Researcher</title>
            <course_code>183</course_code>
            <provider_name>Institute For Academic Development</provider_name>
            <referral_url/>
            <course_category>PhD HSS Res Plan,PhD Comp,PhD SCE Res Plan,PhD MVM Res Plan</course_category>
            <provider_category>Course</provider_category>
            <description><![CDATA[
            <p>What can you do to make yourself a more effective PhD researcher and get the most out of your PhD?</p>
<p>This interactive and intensive 2-day course has been designed for first and second year PhD students and will look at practical ways to increase your effectiveness and meet the challenges of your PhD.</p>
<p>The course will cover:</p>
<ul>
<li>PhD project planning</li>
<li>Effective working practices</li>
<li>Working with others in the      research environment</li>
<li>Maximising your impact</li>
<li>Managing your supervisor</li>
<li>Negotiating</li>
<li>Getting feedback</li>
<li>Making the most of your      PhD&nbsp;- planning for the future</li>
</ul>
<p>Participants work in groups to work on a range of activities. From this you will gain awareness of your performance as an individual and in a team. You will use and develop skills that are essential for a researcher such as communication, planning, time management, problem solving, leadership and assertiveness, as well as building a greater self-awareness of your learning and working styles. The course was developed at the University of Edinburgh with support from Vitae and has been attended by thousands of researchers at universities across the UK. It was devised with input from tutors from academia, industry and other sectors to ensure its relevance to PhD research and future careers.</p>
<p>This course relates to domains A1, A2, A3, B2, B3, C1, and C2 of the <a href="http://www.ed.ac.uk/schools-departments/institute-academic-development/research-roles/research-only-staff/career-management/researcher-framework">RDF</a>.</p>
            ]]></description>
            <further_details/>
            <contact_details>
                <email>iad.phd@ed.ac.uk</email>
                <phone>0131 651 7188</phone>
            </contact_details>
            <single_attendance>-1</single_attendance>
            <prerequisites/>


                <delivery>
                      <delivery_start_date>05-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
                      <machine_date>20150205</machine_date>
                      <event_group_id>10450</event_group_id>
                      <max_places>25</max_places>
                      <bookings>0</bookings>
                      <status>CURRENT</status>
                      <waiting_list>Y</waiting_list>
                      <reminder_url/>
                      <delivery_title/>
                      <delivery_description/>
                      <delivery_url/>
                      <delivery_keywords/>
                      <allow_booking>P</allow_booking>
                      <schedule>
                            <event>
                              <machine_date>20150205</machine_date>
                              <start_date>05-Feb-2015</start_date>
                              <start_time>09:30</start_time>
                              <end_time>16:45</end_time>
                              <final_booking_date>04-Feb-2015</final_booking_date> 
                              <day_of_week>Thursday </day_of_week>
                              <tutor/>
                              <location>
                                <room>Room 1.07, Main Library</room>
                                <building>Central Area</building>
                              </location>
                            </event>
                      </schedule>
                      <eligibility/>
                      <eligibility_display>DO NOT DISPLAY THIS</eligibility_display>
                      <eligibility_rules>
                        <eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> 1st Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> 1st Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> 1st Years</eligibility_rule>
                      </eligibility_rules>
                      <costing>
                            <charging_type>Charging URL</charging_type>
                            <charge_url/>
                      </costing>
                </delivery>

          </course>


          <course>
            <title>Maximising Your Influence At Meetings </title>
            <course_code>589</course_code>
            <provider_name>Institute For Academic Development</provider_name>
            <referral_url/>
            <course_category>PhD Comp,PhD SCE Coms,PhD MVM Res Plan,PhD MVM Prof Dev,PhD MVM IT,PhD MVM Coms,PhD HSS Res Plan,PhD HSS Prof Dev,PhD HSS IT,PhD HSS Coms</course_category>
            <provider_category>Course</provider_category>
            <description><![CDATA[
            <p>This is a highly participative 2-hour session to explore how you can become more effective and influential at meetings, thus developing a key everyday work skill.</p>
<p>The session includes:-</p>
<ul>
<li>Defining effective meetings</li>
<li>Active listening</li>
<li>Encouraging good participation</li>
<li>Identifying and practising the important verbal behaviours of meetings</li>
<li>Dealing with difficult behaviour</li>
</ul>
<p>This course relates to domains D1, D2, and D3 of the <a href="http://www.ed.ac.uk/schools-departments/institute-academic-development/research-roles/research-only-staff/career-management/researcher-framework">RDF</a>.</p>
<p>Pre-Course Work</p>
<p>Please give some thought, before attending the session, to the following questions:-</p>
<ol>
<li>Why are meetings one of the most important methods of communicating in organisations?</li>
<li>Reflect on one or more meetings in which you have been involved and assess the success of these meetings in terms of outcomes.</li>
</ol>
            ]]></description>
            <further_details/>
            <contact_details>
                <email>iad.phd@ed.ac.uk</email>
                <phone>0131 651 7188</phone>
            </contact_details>
            <single_attendance>0</single_attendance>
            <prerequisites/>


                <delivery>
                      <delivery_start_date>10-Dec-2014</delivery_start_date>
                      <machine_date>20141210</machine_date>
                      <event_group_id>10606</event_group_id>
                      <max_places>20</max_places>
                      <bookings>11</bookings>
                      <status>CURRENT</status>
                      <waiting_list>Y</waiting_list>
                      <reminder_url/>
                      <delivery_title/>
                      <delivery_description/>
                      <delivery_url/>
                      <delivery_keywords/>
                      <allow_booking>Y</allow_booking>
                      <schedule>
                            <event>
                              <machine_date>20141210</machine_date>
                              <start_date>10-Dec-2014</start_date>
                              <start_time>09:30</start_time>
                              <end_time>11:30</end_time>
                              <final_booking_date>09-Dec-2014</final_booking_date> 
                              <day_of_week>Wednesday</day_of_week>
                              <tutor/>
                              <location>
                                <room>Room 11.18 David Hume Tower</room>
                                <building>Central Area</building>
                              </location>
                            </event>
                      </schedule>
                      <eligibility/>
                      <eligibility_display>DO NOT DISPLAY THIS</eligibility_display>
                      <eligibility_rules>
                        <eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years </eligibility_rule>
                      </eligibility_rules>
                      <costing>
                            <charging_type>Charging URL</charging_type>
                            <charge_url/>
                      </costing>
                </delivery>

          </course>


          <course>
            <title>Practical Project Management for Research Students</title>
            <course_code>849</course_code>
            <provider_name>Institute For Academic Development</provider_name>
            <referral_url/>
            <course_category>MScR Comp,PhD SCE Res Plan,PhD MVM Res Plan,PhD HSS Res Plan,PhD Comp,MScR SCE Res Plan,MScR MVM Res Plan,MScR HSS Res Plan</course_category>
            <provider_category>Course</provider_category>
            <description><![CDATA[
            <p>This one day course will introduce you to project management, with a focus on the development of practical skills.&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>You will learn how to:</p>
<ul>
<li>Set clear and realistic objectives</li>
<li>Plan, organise, and document your research project&nbsp; </li>
<li>Identify your stakeholders, and to understand their needs</li>
<li>Manage stakeholder expectations</li>
<li>Manage risks and issues, including changes to scope</li>
<li>Review and learn from strengths and weaknesses identified on completion&nbsp; of a project.&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>The session will include presented content, class discussion, and group exercises centred on a research project scenario.&nbsp; There is also a course handbook for reference.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>You should attend if you want to:</p>
<ul>
<li>Understand more about project management, the role of the project manager, and project success</li>
<li>Learn about the lifecycle of a project</li>
<li>Increase your confidence in managing projects</li>
<li>Obtain tools and techniques that you can start to use immediately</li>
<li>Discuss the challenges of research projects with other research staff.</li>
</ul>
<p>This course relates to domains B1, B2, and C2 of the <a href="http://www.ed.ac.uk/schools-departments/institute-academic-development/research-roles/research-only-staff/career-management/researcher-framework">RDF</a>.</p>
            ]]></description>
            <further_details/>
            <contact_details>
                <email>iad.phd@ed.ac.uk</email>
                <phone>0131 651 7188</phone>
            </contact_details>
            <single_attendance>0</single_attendance>
            <prerequisites/>


                <delivery>
                      <delivery_start_date>21-Apr-2015</delivery_start_date>
                      <machine_date>20150421</machine_date>
                      <event_group_id>10700</event_group_id>
                      <max_places>20</max_places>
                      <bookings>0</bookings>
                      <status>CURRENT</status>
                      <waiting_list>Y</waiting_list>
                      <reminder_url/>
                      <delivery_title/>
                      <delivery_description/>
                      <delivery_url/>
                      <delivery_keywords/>
                      <allow_booking>P</allow_booking>
                      <schedule>
                            <event>
                              <machine_date>20150421</machine_date>
                              <start_date>21-Apr-2015</start_date>
                              <start_time>09:30</start_time>
                              <end_time>17:00</end_time>
                              <final_booking_date>20-Apr-2015</final_booking_date> 
                              <day_of_week>Tuesday  </day_of_week>
                              <tutor/>
                              <location>
                                <room>Room 1.09, Main Library</room>
                                <building>Central Area</building>
                              </location>
                            </event>
                      </schedule>
                      <eligibility/>
                      <eligibility_display>DO NOT DISPLAY THIS</eligibility_display>
                      <eligibility_rules>
                        <eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years </eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule>
                      </eligibility_rules>
                      <costing>
                            <charging_type>Charging URL</charging_type>
                            <charge_url/>
                      </costing>
                </delivery>

                <delivery>
                      <delivery_start_date>12-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
                      <machine_date>20150212</machine_date>
                      <event_group_id>10699</event_group_id>
                      <max_places>20</max_places>
                      <bookings>0</bookings>
                      <status>CURRENT</status>
                      <waiting_list>Y</waiting_list>
                      <reminder_url/>
                      <delivery_title/>
                      <delivery_description/>
                      <delivery_url/>
                      <delivery_keywords/>
                      <allow_booking>P</allow_booking>
                      <schedule>
                            <event>
                              <machine_date>20150212</machine_date>
                              <start_date>12-Feb-2015</start_date>
                              <start_time>09:30</start_time>
                              <end_time>17:00</end_time>
                              <final_booking_date>11-Feb-2015</final_booking_date> 
                              <day_of_week>Thursday </day_of_week>
                              <tutor/>
                              <location>
                                <room>Room 1.11, Main Library</room>
                                <building>Central Area</building>
                              </location>
                            </event>
                      </schedule>
                      <eligibility/>
                      <eligibility_display>DO NOT DISPLAY THIS</eligibility_display>
                      <eligibility_rules>
                        <eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>PhD</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> HSS</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years </eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> SCE</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule>MScR</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> MVM</eligibility_rule><eligibility_rule> All Years</eligibility_rule>
                      </eligibility_rules>
                      <costing>
                            <charging_type>Charging URL</charging_type>
                            <charge_url/>
                      </costing>
                </delivery>

          </course>


          <course>
            <title>Statistical Consultancy Workshop </title>
            <course_code>3512</course_code>
            <provider_name>Institute For Academic Development</provider_name>
            <referral_url/>
            <course_category>PhD MVM Res Plan,PhD SCE Res Plan,PhD HSS Res Plan,PhD Comp</course_category>
            <provider_category>Course</provider_category>
            <description><![CDATA[
            <p>A half-day workshop for doctoral research students to discuss their research projects and data analysis needs. Led by an experienced medical statistician, the session will provide an opportunity for up to 5 participants to present a brief (5 minute) summary of their work, and then to lead a discussion of the statistical issues raised. Each participant presenting should take away some ideas for the most appropriate and robust statistical methods that they should employ in their projects subsequently. There will also be room for up to 10 non-presenting participants - they will be very welcome to observe and to take part in discussions and may take away some valuable insights of their own.</p>
<p>&nbsp;The workshop is intended to provide support to students from the College of Medicine and Veterinary Medicine who are carrying out research in medical or biomedical areas. However, students from other disciplines/ colleges may find something of value too, as many of the general issues remain the same regardless of research topic. We would be very happy for non-CMVM students to participate.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Please register as either a presenting or non-presenting participant.&nbsp; </strong></p>
<p>If you have booked a "presenting" place, please don't spend too much time preparing for that. An outline of the general context and aims of your research is quite sufficient, and that may need little supporting material. There will be a PC available for use of PowerPoint, but think about using at most 4-5 slides.</p>
<p><strong>The 5 presenting places are available on a first come-first served basis</strong>.</p>
            ]]></description>
            <further_details/>
            <contact_details>
                <email>iad.phd@ed.ac.uk</email>
                <phone>0131 651 7188</phone>
            </contact_details>
            <single_attendance>-1</single_attendance>
            <prerequisites/>


          </course>


        </courses>
```

What would be the solution for me to sort by date?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<xsl:sort select="@machine_date" data-type="numeric" order="ascending"/>
```

cannot work, because (1) `machine_date` in your example is an **element**, not an **attribute** and (2) `"numeric"` is not a valid data-type value.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:sort select="machine_date" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

This is assuming you are sorting the parent element of `<machine_date>` - hard to tell, because your example is incomplete.

---

### Added:

Assuming you want to sort the courses by their delivery date, try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/courses">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="course">
            <xsl:sort select="delivery/machine_date"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="delivery/delivery_start_date"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>
   <course>
      <title>Statistical Consultancy Workshop </title>
   </course>
   <course>
      <title>Maximising Your Influence At Meetings </title>
      <delivery_start_date>10-Dec-2014</delivery_start_date>
   </course>
   <course>
      <title>How to be an Effective Researcher</title>
      <delivery_start_date>05-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </course>
   <course>
      <title>Managing Your Research Project</title>
      <delivery_start_date>15-Apr-2015</delivery_start_date>
      <delivery_start_date>09-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </course>
   <course>
      <title>Practical Project Management for Research Students</title>
      <delivery_start_date>21-Apr-2015</delivery_start_date>
      <delivery_start_date>12-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </course>
</courses>
```

---

Or perhaps this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/courses">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="course/delivery">
            <xsl:sort select="machine_date"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../title"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="delivery_start_date"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>
   <delivery>
      <title>Maximising Your Influence At Meetings </title>
      <delivery_start_date>10-Dec-2014</delivery_start_date>
   </delivery>
   <delivery>
      <title>How to be an Effective Researcher</title>
      <delivery_start_date>05-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </delivery>
   <delivery>
      <title>Managing Your Research Project</title>
      <delivery_start_date>09-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </delivery>
   <delivery>
      <title>Practical Project Management for Research Students</title>
      <delivery_start_date>12-Feb-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </delivery>
   <delivery>
      <title>Managing Your Research Project</title>
      <delivery_start_date>15-Apr-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </delivery>
   <delivery>
      <title>Practical Project Management for Research Students</title>
      <delivery_start_date>21-Apr-2015</delivery_start_date>
   </delivery>
</courses>
```

Comment: Apologies, I have amended the question to show example data.

Comment: @Alex6534 It's still not clear. There's nothing to sort in your example - you only have one of everything.

Comment: @Alex6534 Except for the actual output you expect. I've taken a guess, but I don't believe it's correct. Being laconic is not a good policy when asking for help.